# Quick search event on website does not work when the page is opened by Robot

Tags: robotframework

I am testing a page with the Robot Framework and on this page there is a search that from the moment you type the third letter starts to do a smart search and starts to bring options of words that start with those three letters, for example

JOS --> Jose; Joseilton; Joseph; ...
[image]

When I do this manually this search works correctly, but when I run it with the Robot it does not work, it seems the search event is not triggered by the Robot. Even leaving the page open at the end of execution, if I manually enter the information in the search field it does not work.

Has anyone been through this or has any idea of what it might be? I have tried with Input Text, Press Keys, and even with Javascript, but it did not work.

Comment: Most likely the page is implemented in a way that it monitors physical keyboard press/release events - which are not triggered with selenium.   If you are *testing* this site, file a bug report, if  not .. oh well, maybe some alternative mechanism might work like directly injecting keyboard events from outside the browser (like pyautogui or similar)

Comment: Yes, I am testing the website, but how do I open a bug for this? The developer will certainly say that it is a problem with automation, as it works manually.

Comment: hypothesis is that the autosearch is wired into keyboard events, not channges in the textfield. It works for human input, not for the bot.  This indicates lack of "testability" - app works but it doesn't fulfill the other requirements of it being tested by autiomation.  If you are paid for this, you open a bug - and explain that It Is A Bug .. Google for "testability" if you need to familiarize with the term.

Comment: Now, there are ofcourse ways someone can mitigate these sort of issues and they can be build in into "automation framework" but they most often are not generalized solutions where one size fits all and thus cannot be integrated into general solutions like selenium or browser library for RF - tl;dr  Issues is 100% solvable in your side without pestering your dev with bug report *but* it is still a testability issue (*once you verify that the update is actually keyboard events triggered) and you should file a bug..

Comment: Btw, i did make assumption that this is with SeleniumLibrary ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SeleniumLibrary. Thank you, I'll talk with the DEV about this.